# custom option decimal point validation in magento

Tags: custom-options

custom option decimal point validation in magento 
like : xxx.xxxxxx  x is a number

Is it possible to validate the below condition

3 digits before decimal and 6 after decimal. xxx.xxxxxx

Comment: Try this `round(xxx.xxxxxx, 6)`.

Answer (score 3):

Since custom options are using the standard Magento validation library you can write your own validation method.

```
Validation.add('validate-customfloat','Input must be in the form of 000.000000',function(v){
    return // true or false, put your code here
});
```

Check out this [Inchoo post](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/) for more information about custom validation. Now all you have to do is add the class `validate-customfloat` to your input field on the frontend

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,But i m using the below code return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) || /^\s*?([\d\,]+(\.\d{6,6})?|\.\d{6,6})\s*$/.test(v);  Its returning the me 12.656565 after decimal 6 digit validation . but i need also before decimal point  3 digit validation. wright now i m able to submit any number before decimal